# DynamoDB - Read an item and return an array size

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an item in a DynamoDB table. The item looks like this:

```
{
  data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
  more_data: [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
}
```

Using a ProjectionExpression, I can do a `GetItem` and only return `data`, or return `data[0]`. But there are two things that I can't figure out:

- How can I return an array size? `data.SIZE` ?
- How can I return a subset of an array? `data[2-10]`

The ProjectionExpression documentation doesn't seem to cover this. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

1) DynamoDB doesn't have a function to get the size of the **`List`** attribute. The size of the array element can be found at the client side using the `length` function.

The `data.Item.records.length` gives the length of the array element `records`. The `records` is the list in the DynamoDB table.

```
docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        console.log(data.Item[0].records.length);
    }
});
```

2) Reg the sub-array, the syntax should be something like this. The DynamoDB doesn't support the range like `'records[1-3]'`.

```
ProjectionExpression: 'records[0], records[1]',
```

3) DynamoDB doesn't have a function to get the last item in a List. However, you can get it at client side. I have the `records` list. I got the last element using `itemValue.records[itemValue.records.length - 1]`

```
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

        data.Items.forEach(function(itemValue) {
            console.log (itemValue.records[itemValue.records.length - 1]);
        });     
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Is there a projection expression that returns the last item of an array?

Comment: So, how could we use a projection expresion over all items in list? example: 

    records[*].name / records[*].name / records.name

Answer (score 1):

It's better to post the three questions should be in three pages.

For (3):

In current(22 Jun 2021) [example of documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html), they used `size(info.actors)` to get the size.
You can use this: `'size(#list)'` to get the size of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately still in 2024 there seems to be no way to get the length of a list element from a `DynamoDB` `Table`.

Same as the answer from 2016, we have to `get_item` to get the length of the list on the client-side.

`python` `boto3` example:

```py
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table(MY_TABLE)

response = table.get_item(
    Key={"keyName": "bla"},
)

history = response["Item"]["List"]
list_length = len(history) # type: ignore
```

This shouldn't throw any errors. The `# type: ignore` will keep your `LSP` from complaining.